# Get CPU usage, memory usage and network usage of an application using Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

How can I retrieve the CPU usage (preferably in %), memory usage (preferably in %) and network usage (preferably in Kbs) of another android application from my application given I have package name, PID and UID of the target application. I'm using Kotlin.

Upon researching over internet and using ChatGPT a bit I wrote these functions, but they always return 0. Given below is the code I'm using.

```
import android.app.ActivityManager
import android.content.Context
import android.net.TrafficStats
import android.util.Log
import java.io.BufferedReader
import java.io.File
import java.io.FileReader
import java.io.IOException

fun getNetworkUsageInKB(uid: Int) {
    val rxBytes = TrafficStats.getUidRxBytes(uid) // Received bytes
    val txBytes = TrafficStats.getUidTxBytes(uid) // Transmitted bytes

    val totalBytes = rxBytes + txBytes
    val totalKB = totalBytes / 1024

    Log.d("Network Usage", totalKB.toString())
}

fun getMemoryUsage(context: Context, pid: Int) {
    val activityManager = context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE) as ActivityManager
    val memoryInfo = ActivityManager.MemoryInfo()
    activityManager.getMemoryInfo(memoryInfo)
    val totalMemory = memoryInfo.totalMem
    val availableMemory = memoryInfo.availMem
    val usedMemory = totalMemory - availableMemory

    Log.d("Memory Info", "Total: $totalMemory, Available: $availableMemory, Used: $usedMemory")

    val processMemoryInfo = activityManager.getProcessMemoryInfo(intArrayOf(pid))
    val appMemory = processMemoryInfo[0].totalPss * 1024L

    Log.d("App Memory", "$appMemory")
    Log.d("Memory Usage", "${(appMemory.toFloat() / usedMemory.toFloat()) * 100}%")
}

fun getCpuUsage(pid: Int) {
    var cpuUsage = 0.0

    val statFile = File("/proc/$pid/stat")
    if (!statFile.exists()) {
        Log.d("CPU Usage", "$cpuUsage")
    }

    try {
        val reader = BufferedReader(FileReader(statFile))
        val stat = reader.readLine()
        reader.close()

        val fields = stat.split(" ")
        val utime = fields[13].toLong()
        val stime = fields[14].toLong()
        val cutime = fields[15].toLong()
        val cstime = fields[16].toLong()
        val startTime = fields[21].toLong()

        val total = utime + stime + cutime + cstime
        val uptime = System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000

        val elapsedTime = uptime - (startTime / 100)

        cpuUsage = 100.0 * (total / 100.0) / elapsedTime.toDouble()
    } catch (e: IOException) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    }

    Log.d("CPU Usage", "$cpuUsage%")
}
```